# How can I see if an element is a "br"

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I see if an element is a "br"?
I have tried to get it via .attr("type") and .type() but it always returns undefined!
It would work on a input or button but not on a br element.

Comment: `if (elem.localName == 'br') {...}` ?

Comment: `.attr("type")` doesn't work on an input or button in the same sense: it doesn't tell you that the element is an `<input>` or `<button>`, it tells you the type of the `<input>` or `<button>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about just `$(element).is('br')`? For example:

```
<div class='tested' id='first'>
  <br class='tested' id='second' />
</div>

...
$('.tested').each(function() {
  var id = this.id;   
  if ($(this).is('br')) {
    console.log(id + ' is <br>');
  }
  else {
    console.log(id + ' is not <br>');
  }
});
// first is not <br>
// second is <br>​
```

Comment: I have tried this but it always returns false `console.log($(this).parent().children().is('br'));`

Comment: @mrmoor Because `children` returns you a collection of elements. You should filter it with something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8nFJn/).

Answer (score 9):

Use the `.tagName` or `.nodeName` property.
Then compare the value to `"BR"`.

Comment: This really is the most efficient way. Converting an object to jQuery solely for the purpose of performing a comparison against it is far slower than native JS.

Comment: But the OP probably already works with $(element) here, so no conversion (again, probably) is necessary.

Comment: make sure it is CAPITALIZED "BR"

Answer (score 4):

by `element.tagName` you can get the name of the tag

```
if (element.tagName=="br")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="test">
    <br>
</div>
```

--

```
var tag = $("#test").children().first().prop('tagName'); //returns BR
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jCsyC/1/)

```
var isTag = $("#test").children().first().is('br');  //returns true/false
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jCsyC/2/)